# How to set font-size in summernote?

Tags: javascript, summernote

I have been using summernote as my default text editor but I haven't been able to set a particular font-size by default when i initialize it.

so far I have tried

```
$('.active-textcontainer').summernote({
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
        ],
         height:150,
         fontsize:'18px'
    });
```

and

```
$('.active-textcontainer').summernote({
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
        ],
         height:150,
         fontsize:'18'
    });
```

Ant help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `fontSize` with an upper-case `S`?

Comment: @torzaburo at first I also make some tries with `fontSize:'18px'`, `fontSize:18`, `font-size`... with no luck, then I take a look on `summernote` and the easy way I saw it's to use `$('.note-editable').css('font-size','18px');` as I explain in the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've never use `summernote`, however looking at the [API](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/features.html#api) there is nothing (at least now) to specify default font size, I make a test doing some tries like you and seems that no one works.

A possible solution to this is to apply directly the `font-size` style to the editor `div` using `jQuery` because when you initialize `summernote` in an object always create the follow `div` : `<div class="note-editable" ...>...</div>`. So you can do the follow after initialization `$('.note-editable').css('font-size','18px');` in your code this could be:

```
$('.active-textcontainer').summernote({
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
    ],
     height:150
});

$('.note-editable').css('font-size','18px');
```

This solution it's a little tricky an if the `class` name of the `div` editor change on the next version this will not work however maybe it's enough for your case.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I thought about this, if there are no other options, I am going to use this. Thanks, just wanted to be sure if there was an option to do this.

Comment: I've never work with `summernote` before so I'm not 100% sure that there is another way to do it, however I take a look at the API as I said in my answer and I didn't see another option. Until you don't found another way you can use this option `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font size of the currently selected text,

```
$('.summernote').summernote('fontSize', 40);
```

but there seems to be no API to select text.

Being unable to set the default font size is quite strange, so I [filed an issue in their repo](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1316).

Answer (score 1):

or set the default via css

```
.note-editor .note-editable {
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```