# summernote font size doesn't shows

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, summernote

I'm trying to use the summernote to display the text editor.
I have used this code to display it:

```
$('#editor').summernote({
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['text', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'color', 'clear']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['height', ['height']],
            ['size', ['fontsize']],
            ['font', ['fontname']],
        ],
        fontsize: '18px',
        onblur: function() {
            var text = $('#editor').code();
            text = text.replace("<br>", " ");
            $('#description').val(text);
        },
        lang: language_value
    });
```

but only font-size doesn't display.
Is there any other way to display it?

Answer (score 0):

it's not working because the api doesn't allow you to pass in a `fontsize` parameter in the config/settings.

here are the [api docs](http://summernote.org/jsduck/)

here is a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011485/how-to-set-font-size-in-summernote) with a hack/workaround to set it

Comment: but looking in the demo: http://www.usrtriton.nl/assets/bower/summernote/features.html#Custom%20toolbar I found in the Custom_toolbar section that the font size is displayed. I don't want to set a default value I just want to display it.

Comment: I see, then you'd need `['fontsize', ['fontsize']],` instead of `['size', ['fontsize']],` as per the demo.

Comment: `['fontsize', ['fontsize']],` is whats in the demo, have you tried just using the demo example in your app/site to see if it works?

Comment: The demo code works on the demo site, maybe something else is to blame

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
```

Instead of

```
['size', ['fontsize']],
```

**UPDATE** : your code seems to be working just fine https://jsfiddle.net/ymef5xac/

Comment: as I already mentioned in comments I used this but it also doesn't work.

Comment: @DevSondes , sorry didn't notice it, anyway I updated my answer with a jsfiddle link, I don't understand your problem since it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

fontsize feature is merged with summernote.

refer to https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/1028

download latest summernote version (0.6.6)