# Summernote set default font size and font

Tags: javascript, summernote

I'm using last version  summernote library. How i can set default font size and font?
I'm trying like this, but its not working:

```
 $('.text-editor').summernote({
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'strikethrough', 'clear']],
            ['fontname', ['fontname']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['height', ['height']],
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'hr']],
            ['view', ['codeview']]
        ],
        fontsize: '16'
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/142/

Comment: Try with `fontSize: 16` and `fontName: 'Arial'`

Comment: @yuriy636 still not working. https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/142/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A possible solution to this is to apply directly the font-size style to the editor div using jQuery

```
$('.active-textcontainer').summernote({
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
    ],
     height:150
});

$('.note-editable').css('font-size','18px');
```

More .. [How to set font-size in summernote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011485/how-to-set-font-size-in-summernote)

Thanks

Comment: Oh.. I found the reason. But little thing. It change font size only when i click in editor field. Maybe you know way to fix this?

Comment: Ok i found way to fix this. So just need to add to .css file like this:
`.note-editable {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 16px!important;
}`

Comment: If you have placeholder in the editor, you should also set  `.note-placeholder {
        font-size: 16px;
     }`  , otherwise the placeholder will have a different font size with text.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS to your own CSS file to override the settings from summernote.css:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------
   SummerNote
----------------------------------------------------- */

.note-editable { 
    font-family: 'Poppins' !important; 
    font-size: 15px !important; 
    text-align: left !important; 
    
    height: 350px !important;
    
}
```

NB. For this example, I am using the following summernote initialization:

```
var gArrayFonts = ['Amethysta','Poppins','Poppins-Bold','Poppins-Black','Poppins-Extrabold','Poppins-Extralight','Poppins-Light','Poppins-Medium','Poppins-Semibold','Poppins-Thin'];

jQuery('#' + myID).summernote({
    fontNames: gArrayFonts,
    fontNamesIgnoreCheck: gArrayFonts,
    fontSizes: ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '18', '20', '22' , '24', '28', '32', '36', '40', '48'],
    followingToolbar: false,
    dialogsInBody: true,
    toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['style'],
    ['style', ['clear', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
    ['fontname', ['fontname']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],       
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['table', ['table']],
    ['view', ['codeview']]
    ]
});
```

And of course you need to load all these fonts via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
        $('#summernote').summernote('fontName', 'Arial');
        $('#summernote').summernote('fontSize', '12');
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your editor is not running with simple text, you need to bind something to work it.
Add this code into your summernote

```
$('#summernote').summernote('formatPara');
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that using $('.note-editable').css('font-size','18px') seams to the cause the page to focus on the note when loading, which in my case caused the page to scroll to the bottom every time.

in the summernote.css, adding **font-size: 16px;** to **.note-editor** seems to do the trick without the scrolling problem.

just make sure this is in your summernote.css

```
.note-editor {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;    
}
```